# Нужна ли запятая после "хотя"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "хотя" в этом предложении: "Хотя(,) толком-то она ничего и не увидела, ведь за окном была уже ночь и сияла серебристая луна"?

Answer (score 4):

> Нужна ли запятая после "хотя"...

**Не нужна.**

См. *Остроумова О., Фрамполь О.  "Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений":*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Иногда слово "хотя" выделяется авторскими знаками, например:

Хотя, почему бы не попробовать? 
Нет, конечно, я не рассчитывала, что мне бросятся на шею (хотя, почему бы и нет, черт побери! (Дина Рубина).

Хотя… почему бы и не потешить почтеннейшую публику?

Но в приведенном примере это присоединительный уступительный союз, запятая не нужна.

Answer (score -1):

Если по правилам русского языка, то не обособляется.
Но некоторые писатели, как было сказано выше, пренебрегают этим правилом.

Comment: Каким правилам? Каким этим правилом? Какие некоторые писатели?